# Trigonometry / Obtuse angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\cos A = 4/5$ and $\sin B = 5/13$, where $A$ is a acute and $B$ is obtuse, find, without evaluating the angles $A$ and $B$, the values of

a) $\sin (A-B)$

b) $\cos (A+B)$

I'm stuck figuring out the obtuse angle.

I know obtuse is somewhere inbetween 180 and 90 degrees but i'm confused on how to apply on it..

Comment: For (a), you will want to use $\sin(A-B)=\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$. We already know $\cos A$ and $\sin B$. To use the formula, we need $\sin A$ and $\cos B$. We have $\sin^2 B+\cos^2 B=1$, so $\cos^2 B=1-\frac{12^2}{13^2}=\frac{25}{13^2}$. So $\cos B=\pm \frac{5}{13}$. **This is where** $B$ obtuse comes in. Because cosine is negative between $90$ degrees and $180$ degrees, $\cos B=-\frac{5}{13}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$\sin(A-B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)-\sin(B)\cos(A)$$
And
$$\cos(A+B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B)$$
and further more to gain a sine given a cosine of vice versa remember the pythagorean trigonometric identity, ie
$$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$
Thus
$$\sin(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}$$
$$\cos(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$$
and remember that the cosine of an obtuse angle is always negative.

Comment: i have done part for cos= 4/5 but i'm lost at sin b= 5/13 obtuse angle how do i apply it?

Comment: what do you mean by apply it? just plug it in. an obtuse angle is no different than an acute one except for the fact that its cosine is negative.

Comment: Wrong! Add $\pm$ in front of both \sqrt.

Comment: whops, sorry man, this kinda slipped from my mind